# Mirroring actions on two similar CheckListBoxes

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two CheckListBoxes (`chklbStep`, `chklbSort`) and they contain similar checklistbox items. For example under chklbStep it will look like `"step_factor_20120828"` and under chklbSort it will look like `srt_factor_20120828`:

```
chklbStep                 chklbSort 
---------                 ---------
step_factor_20120828      srt_factor_20120828
step_factor_20120829
```

The total items from each list do not match completely (sometimes a matching item on the chklbSort does not exist). chklbStep is the 'master' checkboxlist which contains everything.

I am trying to mirror the check/uncheck actions on the two lists considering that the user can check/uncheck only on the chklbStep. The problem on the code below is that the items on the chklbSort never get Unchecked if the user has unchecked the corresponding item from the chklbStep.
Any ideas?

```
 Private Sub chklbStep_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) 
 Handles chklbStep.ItemCheck

    Dim listCheckedItems As New List(Of String)()
    Dim listUNcheckedItems As New List(Of String)()
    '
    For Each item In chklbStep.CheckedItems
        listCheckedItems.Add(item.ToString())
    Next

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        listCheckedItems.Add(chklbStep.Items(e.Index).ToString())
    End If

    'Trying to clear the items but this action does not work since the 
    'Sub is only called only on Checking an item

    For i As Integer = 0 To chklbSort.Items.Count - 1
        chklbSort.SetItemChecked(i, False)
    Next


    For Each item As String In listCheckedItems

        Dim sSort As String = Regex.Replace(item, "step", "srt", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim iSort As Integer = chklbSort.Items.IndexOf(sSort)
        If iSort > -1 Then

            chklbSort.SetItemChecked(iSort, True)


        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: since the list contents are not the same, the index of an item in the left one may not have the same index in the other one. so e.Index is not useful.  You might be better off storing Class objects in them with a definite key such as "factor_20120828" so you can find them easily.

Comment: @Plutonix The check option works fine. What I need only is the uncheck

Comment: It's weird that the event doesn't fire. But you could change the logic and attach your sub to the Click event, scan your entire main checklist and do the rest exactly as you are doing. May be no the best solution but it should work.

Comment: *the Sub is only called only on Checking an item* is not true: As per Object Browser, it `Occurs when the checked state of an item changes.`  If *the user can check/uncheck only on the chklbStep*, the why is the other one a CheckedListBox at all?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by modifying the code:

```
  If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
         listCheckedItems.Add(chklbStep.Items(e.Index).ToString())
  Else
         listCheckedItems.Remove(chklbStep.Items(e.Index).ToString())
  End If
```